# Usage of WorksheetFunction.Trim in Excel VBA is removing coloring in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm developing in VBA Excel and I discovered that I use WorksheetFunction.Trim(Cells(1,1)) where this cells contain any colored element, this element become colored by default.

Here is my code:

```
Cells(4, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(UCase(Cells(4, 2)))
```

Did you see this issue before ?

How can I remove blank in the text without this issue ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Worksheet functions do not affect the format of cells.  You will need to set the interior color of the cell with another line of code.

Comment: When you say "element", do you mean a character?

Comment: If your cell text has different colors set per character then you can't use this approach to trim the content: you'll need to loop over the cell `Characters` collection and remove leading/trailing spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I used this instruction.

```
Cells(4, 2) = Replace(UCase(Cells(4, 2)), " ", "")
```

In fact, my cell contain parameters and we perfers to avoid to have blank between them for visibility.

Comment: This does not preserve the original coloring of characters for me.

Comment: You seem to have answered a different question than the one you posted.

Comment: @DecimalTurn: Yes, the original coloring of characters is kept.

Answer (score 1):

For cells with mixed formatting, replacing the cell value will lose the mixed format: instead you need to work with the cell's `Characters` collection:

```
Sub tester()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("B3:B10").Cells
        TrimAndUppercase c
    Next c
End Sub


Sub TrimAndUppercase(c As Range)

    Dim i, prevSpace As Boolean
    
    If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
        'trim the ends of the text
        Do While Left(c.Value, 1) = " "
            c.Characters(1, 1).Text = ""
        Loop
        Do While Right(c.Value, 1) = " "
            c.Characters(Len(c.Value), 1).Text = ""
        Loop
        'reduce runs of multiple spaces to a single space
        For i = c.Characters.Count To 1 Step -1
            With c.Characters(i, 1)
                If .Text = " " Then
                    'was the previous character a space?
                    If prevSpace Then
                        .Text = "" 'remove this space
                    Else
                        prevSpace = True
                    End If
                Else
                    .Text = UCase(.Text)
                    prevSpace = False
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    End If
   
End Sub
```

Note there are some limits to the length of the text using this method, and it can be a little slow with large ranges.

Comment: +1 For the use of `.Text` and setting characters to "". That is brilliant! 
However per the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.characters), "the `Characters` object isn't a collection." This is why `For Each` can't be used on `Characters`.

Comment: Hello, finally, I used this instruction.

Cells(4, 2) = Replace(UCase(Cells(4, 2)), " ", "")

Comment: That wouldn't satisfy your posted requirment